# React Native with MangoDB through NodeJS

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

As of now i am **React native** mobile app developer... I want to learn Back end also with **NodeJS**... I tried for sample data, it worked well...

created sample like [tutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_first_application.htm)

and Used like [using restful client](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm)

Now how to create and use huge amount of data in back end with **Mango DB** in **NodeJS**...

Is there any simple understanding getting started tutorials for **NodeJs** with **MangoDB**?
Any Help please... Thank you...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Please do not ask such questions on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hackathon-starter
https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter

for NodeJs And MongoDb and Can Manage Api Request With This.